# Merge fairly similar datasets for later comparison with wilcox.test{stats}

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, statistics

I have loaded two datasets as data.frames, named `DF1` and `DF2`. Both have the columns `time` and `area`. `DF1` though has more rows than `DF2`, i.e. more time points (or data points). The `merge` function would allow me to combine the `area` columns of the two datasets `by="time"`, but the time points are dissimilar. `round` isn't useful here (too coarse and duplicates). 
What I actually want to do is to run a two-sample `wilcox.test` (i.e. they don't follow a normal distribution), which doesn't allow for vectors of different length (afaik).

```
> head(DF1)
  timesteps area  time
1         0 1030 40.00
2       100 1031 40.11
3       200 1039 40.22
4       300 1046 40.32
5       400 1053 40.43
6       500 1061 40.54

> head(DF2)
      time      area
1 33.83506  952.7843
2 43.31922  935.7430
3 47.95656 1528.4501
4 52.78808 2400.7030
5 67.29044 5699.4736
6 72.12320 8277.1240
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```
wilcox.test(DF1$time, DF2$time)
```

or area if that is the desired test.

The following works:

```
wilcox.test(rnorm(50), (rnorm(100)+2))
```

Comment: My mistake: I tried to use `wilcox.test(DF1$area,DF2$area, paired = TRUE)` instead of just `wilcox.test(DF1$area,DF2$area)`

Comment: @macro yeah, the signed rank test only makes sense if there is some a priori or design reason for pairing observations across groups.